# Are there any schools with researchers interested in cellular automata?

Tags: soft-question, cellular-automata

I have been working on an independant project focusing on cellular automata and was wondering if this might be something that I could continue on in graduate school somewhere. I've seen some mathematics departments with symbolic dynamics as well as a few CS departments with researchers interested in CA. The list is small though. If anyone knows which departments to look at and/or any specific faculty/programs to look at then I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, my project is sort of taking on a "mathematical" flavor and I was wondering if it would be better to look into mathematics over computer science departments, or is it generally pretty easy to do this type of thing in either.

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053667/is-cellular-automata-something-that-is-studied-in-mathematics-departments) and (now deleted) [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32778/in-what-department-is-cellular-automata-studied).  **Don't do that.**

Comment: this seems to be a topic that had a lot of hype years ago but maybe has faded somewhat due to it not nec leading to new breakthrough insights and being very hard to work on, due to the intrinsic hardness of Turing completeness. eg there is a now-defunct ["evolving cellular automata project"](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~evca/) at Santa Fe institute. maybe there is now less specialization in it as its now crosscutting across very many research institutions. note [wolfram research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Research) has funded some research on it.

Answer (score 6):

The AUTOMATA workshop series focuses on cellular automata:

http://www.eng.u-hyogo.ac.jp/eecs/eecs12/automata2014/

Answer (score 6):

The main teams I know that study cellular automata are in the following laboratories (non-exhaustive list, probably biased towards french labs):

- [LIAFA](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/) in Paris, France
- [Université de Lorraine](http://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/) in Nancy, France
- [LACL](http://www.lacl.fr/fr/lcp) in Créteil, France
- [University of Turku](http://www.utu.fi/en/units/sci/units/math/Pages/home.aspx), Finland

Comment: That's undoubtedly biased towards French labs... Though if you want a more comprehensive list of French labs where Cellular Automata (or related subjects) are studied, have a look at the [SDA2 Working Group](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/~theyssier/sda2/#liste).

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking at North America, [Jeffrey Shallit](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/) does research on the subject at the University of Waterloo.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the MDSC team in I3S lab (http://i3s.unice.fr/), Nice, France

Answer (score 3):

If South America is feasible for you, the [Center for Mathematical Modeling](http://www.cmm.uchile.cl/) at University of Chile has a fairly large and very active research group in symbolic dynamics and related fields, including cellular automata. Also, their emphasis is for the most part more mathematical than computer science-y.